# winston logging from location in yarn 2

Tags: node.js, jestjs, winston, yarnpkg-v2

my log message here is just `info: after all completed` for some reason something is printing `console.log` and `at Console.log` as well as some blank lines for every log message.

```
➤ YN0000: [@bb/common-framework]:     console.log
➤ YN0000: [@bb/common-framework]:           info: after all completed
➤ YN0000: [@bb/common-framework]: 
➤ YN0000: [@bb/common-framework]:       at Console.log (../../../../../.yarn/cache/winston-npm-3.3.3-3fa4527b42-8a9d69c642.zip/node_modules/winston/lib/winston/transports/console.js:79:23)
```

This only seems to happen when running with

```json
    "test:graph": "yarn ts/app/service/packages/graph workspaces foreach --parallel --topological-dev --verbose --recursive run test",
    ":g:jest": "cd $INIT_CWD && jest --collectCoverage --colors --config ../../../../jest.config.js --rootDir .",
    "test": "yarn :g:jest",
```

if I run a single test with, the below, everything is fine

```json
    "jest": "cd $INIT_CWD && jest --forceExit --colors --config jest-vscode.config.js",
```

this is basically a copy and paste of my winston configuration, but into a fresh project the problem didn't rear its head. I doubt this has anything to do with jest, but since I only see this running tests through jest and an in the loop, I can't count it out.

```
import { createLogger, format, transports } from "winston";

describe('something', () => {
  const log = createLogger({
    level: 'debug',
    format: format.combine(
      format.colorize({ level: true, message: false }),
      format.splat(),
      format.simple(),
      format.align(),
      format.padLevels(),
    ),
    transports: [new transports.Console()]
  })

  it('hello', () => {
    log.info('hello world');
  })
})
```

These are the deps I have in the least complicated module I have showing this error.

```json
  "dependencies": {
    "@aurelia/kernel": "dev",
    "@js-joda/core": "npm:^3.2.0",
    "@new10com/axios-logger": "^0.1.4",
    "apollo-server-express": "npm:^2.18.2",
    "axios": "0.21.x",
    "change-case": "npm:^3.1.0",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "find-up": "^5.0.0",
    "graphql": "npm:^14.5.0",
    "logform": "npm:^2",
    "typeorm": "npm:^0.2.28",
    "winston": "3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "npm:26.x",
    "@types/node": "12",
    "jest": "npm:^26",
    "ts-jest": "^26.4.1",
    "type-fest": "^0.18.0",
    "typescript": "^4.0.5"
  }
```

I tried winston 3.3.3  and winston 3.2.x, same results.

Sorry that this is such a poorly reproducible issue, I know this is a long shot. If you have any ideas please share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is coming from jest, it doesn't always seem to do it, so I don't fully understand. https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/9127